# Change Language for Xamarin Android App using Resources

Tags: android, xamarin.android, localization, locale, android-resources

I have a requirement to change language of App on selection of radio buttons. App already has localization implemented using Android Resources. I have tried below solutions in different combinations from Activity as well as normal class, but nothing worked so far:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);  // lang => en-US or nl-BE

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);

var locale = new Java.Util.Locale(lang);
Java.Util.Locale.Default = locale;
Android.Content.Res.Configuration config = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration();
config.Locale = locale;

var context = Application.Context;
context.Resources.Configuration.Locale = locale;
BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config, BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config, context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);

string title = Application.Context.GetString(Resource.String.title_settings);
```

Above 'title' never shows string in language other than that of the device. Any idea what could be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after a bit of hit and trial - Found that I was using a wrong constructor of Locale, and simply changing it started reflecting the updated language. Below is the working code:

```
var locale = new Java.Util.Locale(lang, region); // lang => nl; region => BE
Java.Util.Locale.Default = locale;
var context = Application.Context;
context.Resources.Configuration.Locale = locale;

context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(context.Resources.Configuration, context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
string title = Application.Context.GetString(Resource.String.title_settings); // Reflects text in updated language
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Xamarin docs: [Android Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization) and especially the section "[GetText Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization#gettext-method)".

> To retrieve translated strings in code, use the GetText method and
>   pass the resource ID:
>
> ```
> var cancelText = Resources.GetText (Resource.String.taskcancel);
> ```